# How can I pass an object's constructor function with it to another page in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, google-chrome-extension, constructor

I'm creating a Chrome extension that injects an iframe into the page. The extension passes data (specifically objects) between 3 pages: the page being visited, the iframe content, and background.html

I'm passing objects that were created using a constructor, like so:

```
function url(href, anchorText, altText, linksOut){
    this.href = href;
    this.anchorText = anchorText;
    this.altText = altText;
    this.linksOut = linksOut;
};
```

In the console, an object created this way will look something like this:

```
url {href: "http://www.foo.com", anchorText: "Foo", altText: "", linksOut: Array[42]}
```

I can also see the constructor in the console, attached to the object:

```
__proto__: url
  constructor: function url(href, anchorText, altText, linksOut){
  ...
```

The relevant part being that it has the name of the object/constructor. The problem comes when I pass the data from the page visited to background.html. Pulling up the console here, it has lost its name and becomes a generic (anonymous?) object:

```
Object {href: "http://www.foo.com", anchorText: "Foo", altText: "", linksOut: Array[42]}
```

I can see the constructor has been lost:

```
__proto__: Object
  ...
  constructor: function Object() { [native code] }
  ...
```

**So the question is, is there a way to pass an object between pages and retain the association to its constructor?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages sent between the background page and the content scripts are JSON encoded objects. Your url object is stringified and then parsed on the background page, thus losing its "identity".

**A.)**
If you are looking for a way to pass an object from a content script to the background page, then modify it in the background page and be able to see the changes in the content script, that is not possible, as the objects are different.
Maybe, you could come up with a partial workaround by using the `sendResponse` callback of the **[chrome.runtime.onMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)** listener, but I doubt it is worth the trouble.

**B.)**
If you just need to obtain a copy of the url object being sent from the content script, you could define the constructor in the background page as well and instanciate a new object upon receiving a message. E.g.:

**In background.js:**

```
...
function url(href, anchorText, altText, linksOut) {
    this.href = href;
    this.anchorText = anchorText;
    this.altText = altText;
    this.linksOut = linksOut;
}
...
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    var genericObj = msg.urlObj;
    var urlObjClone = new url(genericObj.href, genericObj.anchorText,
                              genericObj.altText, genericObj.linksOut);
});
...
```

---

(In any case, being more specific about what you are ultimately trying to achieve, might produce better suggestions.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like B would be the best option for me. I was asking mostly for educational purposes, as it didn't seem right that an object would lose its identity like that, so I figured there might be a way to make it retain it that I just didn't know about. Plus it would make it easier to identify what it is in the console.

Either way, thanks and cheers.